# Switching between Cartesian coordinate and polar coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Under what assumption, every non-zero complex number represented in Cartesian coordinate system admits unique polar representation and vice versa ?

Comment: I guess that assumption would have to be the *choice* of argument $\arg(z)$ for the polar representation of the (non-zero) complex number $z$.

Comment: The question seems to imply that certain assumptions are required. But why should that be the case? The transformation between Cartesian coordinates and polar coordinates (and vice versa) is based on the most elementary mathematics: the square root function, the sine and cosine.